# Не получается сохранить текст в юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я хочу сделать так чтобы когда человек вводил текст в Input Fild то он сохранялся и вставлялся в текстовое поле на другой сцене, скрипт написал но он не работает

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SaveInputFieldST1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    private string ST1;

    public InputField inputField;

    private void Start()
    {
        inputField.onEndEdit.AddListener(SaveText);
        LoadText();
    }

    private void SaveText(string text)
    {
        ST1 = text;
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("ST1", ST1);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }

    private void LoadText()
    {
        ST1 = PlayerPrefs.GetString("ST1", "");
        inputField.text = ST1;
    }
}
```

Это не рабочий код, как мне сделать его рабочим

Comment: Как именно вы поняли, что он не работает? Отладку использовали? Метод SaveText вызывается? Или ошибки возникают? Какие?